# Как заставить дополнения в MODX REVO загрузиться?

Tags: cms, modx, плагин

Начинаю знакомиться с modx revo. Установил его, полез устанавливать пакеты и нет ни одного пакета. Добавил нового поставщика (http://modxstore.pro/extras/) все так же нет ни одного пакета. Обновление не помогает. Может я что-то особенное должен был активировать перед установкой пакетов?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
или такая штука крутится вечно
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось, что при использовании пакета OpenServer необходимо устанавливать версию php не выше php5.4. При любой версии старше наблюдается описанная проблема. При младших версиях проблема не наблюдается, все работает корректно.